# How to find a value at an index of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't seem to find anything about this. I'm looping through an array and I want to check if each index is not equal to the string "deleted". Here's my code that doesn't work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sessions.length-1; i++) {
    if (sessions[i] !== "deleted") {
        options += '<option value=\"' + (i+1) + '\">Session ' + (i+1) + '</option>';
    }
}
```

EDIT: What did I do wrong to get downvoted twice without an answer? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `indexOf` function to check for the index of an element in an Array. If the element is not in the Array, `indexOf` will return -1. Remember that an Array's index begins at 0 and not 1.

```js
var sessions = ["something", "something else", "deleted", "null", "a string", "another part of this array"];
console.log("Index of the word 'deleted': " + sessions.indexOf("deleted"));
```

```js
var options = document.getElementById('options');
var sessions = ["something", "something else", "deleted", "null", "a string", "another part of this array"];
var index;
if ((index = sessions.indexOf("deleted")) != -1) {
  options.innerHTML += '<option value=\"' + (index + 1) + '\">Session ' + (index + 1) + '</option>';
}
```

```html
<select id="options"></select>
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but for whatever reason it doesn't in my code. Is this supposed to replace my for loop?

Comment: @Treedot Yes, with this method, no for loop is required.

Comment: Yeah I can't get this to work. When I have this code in place of my for loop, it won't draw anything in the dropdown. Can I ask why (sessions[i] == "deleted" doesn't work? It feels like it should.

Comment: @Treedot `sessions[i] == "deleted"` should work, but my method is faster. Can you post your full code so I can see what the problem is?